# Sigma bond strengths S-S, S-P, P-P

Tags: bond

I want to know how the following sigma bond strength values are calculated.
Like S-S = 1.0, S-P=1.71 And P-P=3.0.

How these 1.0, 1.71, 3.0 came?

Comment: Are there supposed to be units on any of these numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify, these values are relative bond strengths, not absolute bond strength values, which would have units of energy, i.e. Joules, kilocalories, or electron volts. Another detail missed in this question is the fact that these values refer to the bond strength of these types of orbitals directly overlapping along the same axis, as shown in the diagram below.

[image: See here for a picture reference]

You'll notice that these relative bond strengths corresponds the amount of overlap occurring in the orbitals. This gives you a qualitative description, but to actually calculate the relative overlaps we can use quantum mechanics. Remember that these orbitals are really just the probability distributions electrons and can be solved analytically by squaring the wave function. We have a mathematical description of both S and P orbitals. By integrating over the volume in which they overlap, we can calculate the relative overlap between S-S, S-P, P-P, and any other orbital overlaps we might be interested in.

Comment: Does Sigma bond not imply that the overlapping is taking place along the same axis?

Comment: Oh, you are correct. I totally missed that in the question.